# Reduce space between Table number and title in List of Tables

Tags: table-of-contents

I am currently not using any packages for my table of contents, list of figures/tables and would like to keep it that way. Is it possible to reduce the horizontal space between a table number and title in a list of tables without the need to use tocloft/tocstyle/etc ?

Many thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

Pieter

Comment: Which document class do you use?

Comment: \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`article.cls` has

```
\newcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\let\l@table\l@figure
```

You can redefine `\l@table` in the preamble of your document and change the third argument:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@table{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{1.8em}}
\makeatother
```

For consistency's sake, perhaps you could also redefine `\l@figure` accordingly:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{1.8em}}
\renewcommand*\l@table{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{1.8em}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: @PieterOudshoorn You're welcome! If you consider my answer solved your problem, don't forget that you can accept it by clicking the checkmark to its left; in case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: Another question, is there an easy way to put a baselineskip between tables from the main text and those from appendices. Right now, my list of tables looks like:

6   Bla
7   Bla
8   Bla
A.1 Bla
A.2 Bla

Comment: @PieterOudshoorn Just before the appendices add something like `\addtocontents{lot}{\vspace{\baselineskip}}`